# Xcode doesn't recognise firebase storage functions or any errors

Tags: xcode, firebase, cocoapods

After I installed new pods in my file and changed the name.

Xcode no longer detects errors in code I can even write an essay and it won't spot it

Should I change the name back

inside my pod file I see this

```
target 'Blanket' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Flash Chat'

pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
pod 'ChameleonFramework'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'

end
```

In the Target part I changed the name but have also changed the name of my file at the same time.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just to make sure: have you restarted Xcode, cleaned your project, etc.?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up for some reason there was a duplicate of my file in Xcode. After deleting it it worked again